# "hostname match not found" error with firebase sign in with phone number

Tags: javascript, firebase, webview, firebase-authentication

This error only fires when I'm running a webview i made with java, the code works fine using a web browser, it also works on a webview i made with react native, I'm receiving a code on my phone and everything.

It's worth mentioning that I have already authorized my domain in firebase : `Authentication > settings > authorized domains > add domain`

Comment: Please edit your question to include a snippet of the code you are using to sign in with phone number.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.